# Display current date in Kendo grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid like the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.order_num).Title(" Number");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Customer_name).Title("Customer Name").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
        if(ViewBag.odrStatus == "Pending")
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.order_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("TodayDate");
            columns.Bound(c => c.est_ship_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("NextMonthDate");
        }
        else
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.order_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("Order Submittal Date");
            columns.Bound(c => c.est_ship_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        }
        columns.Bound(c => c.Contact_name).Title("Contact Name").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
        columns.Bound(c => c.order_status).Title("Status");
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("details", "order"))
        .PageSize(15)
    )
)
```

I want to check the status of the order. If status is 'pending', then need to display the current date, otherwise display the date from the database.

Can anyone help me to complete this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do that in your controller. Your view is not the right place for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ID).ClientTemplate(DateTime.Now.ToString()).Title("TodayDate");
```

Here p.ID is your unique table id.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. I tried the above one but but not able to get the answer

Comment: if your order number is unique means please try this columns.Bound(p => p.order_num ).ClientTemplate(DateTime.Now.ToString()).Title("TodayDate");.please let me know what comes in that date column

Comment: I tried as you mentioned above, it displays the order_date from databse where it needs to display today's date

Comment: Dont use order_date at the bound. use ordernumber columns.Bound(p => p.order_num ).ClientTemplate(DateTime.Now.ToString()).Title("TodayDate"); for me its working perfect.

Comment: I use if condition there to check order status. Based on that i need to display current date else date from DB. if(ViewBag.odrStatus == "Pending")
        {
         columns.Bound(p => p.order_num ).ClientTemplate(DateTime.Now.ToString()).Title("TodayDate")
            columns.Bound(c => c.est_ship_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("NextMonthDate");
        }
        else
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.order_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("Order Submittal Date");
            columns.Bound(c => c.est_ship_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        }